# How to write integration test to test zuul load balancing with spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-netflix

I am trying to use the TestRestTemplate to make the http call with a relative url:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment=WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class MyApiLoadBalancerIntegrationTests {
    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Test
    public void whenSendRequestMyApiChoosingAnyServer() {
        ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity("/my-api/api-call", String.class);

        assertNotNull("Body was null", responseEntity.getBody());
        assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, responseEntity.getStatusCode());
    }

}
```

This is my application.properties file:

```
zuul.routes.my-api.path= /my-api/**
zuul.routes.my-api.serviceId= my-api-servers

ribbon.eureka.enabled= false
my-api-servers.ribbon.listOfServers= ip1:8080, ip2:8080
```

It does not work properly, I cannot get a straight api call to the server.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I have made it work.

Comment: Could you post your solution as a comment? Running into similar issues.

Comment: I had to switch the zuul ribbon http client library, as the apache http library that is the default was sending the header to compress the content even though the request was a get with no body. zuul.ribbon.okhttp.enabled=true plus this to bring in the dependency in gradle compile group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', name: 'okhttp', version: '3.6.0'